# iOS StarScream, WebSocket sometimes does not reconnect on app foreground

Tags: ios, websocket, starscream

This has been a real brain scratcher for us

We know iOS closes WebSocket connections for apps in the background after a certain period of time.

We noticed that every time this happens, and the app comes back to Foreground, our socket delegate receives the `websocketDidDisconnect` message.
And when things are working, we quickly get the `websocketDidConnect` message.

The assumption here is that StarScream is handling the automatic reconnect on foreground

However, in a small percentage of cases, clients only receive `websocketDidDisconnect` on foreground, but never receive `websocketDidConnect` message.

Furthermore, we attempt to manually determine this disconnect on foreground:

```
private var serverSocket: WebSocket?

init() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reconnect), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)        
}

@objc func reconnect() {
    LogManagerProvider.shared.info("Reconnecting WebSocket")
    LogManagerProvider.shared.info((serverSocket?.isConnected == true) ? "Before Reconnect Attempt: Already Connected" : "Before Reconnect Attempt: Disconnected")
    self.serverSocket?.connect()
}
```

In the case where the socket is back up on foreground, we see `serverSocket.isConnected == true`
But in the case where it's failed, we see `serverSocket.isConnected == false`, and the `connect` call doesn't re-connect the socket as we'd expect, either

Has anybody seen this before, or know what could be the issue?

Comment: Do you found how to solve the issue?

Comment: unfortunately no this is still plaguing us :/